# Is it possible to show headers while scrolling the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, .net-2.0

I am using Gridview in my application. Grid view is binded with the data from the database with some header text. Now what i would like to have is when i scroll the grid view i would like to show the headers while moving the gridview how can i do this

This is what i wrote `McArthey`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <link href="StyleSheet2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlWrapper" runat="server" Height="300px" ScrollBars="Vertical" BorderWidth="1px">                
    <asp:GridView ID="gvTheGrid" runat="server" GridLines="Both" CellPadding="3" CssClass="gvTable" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true">                    
        <columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" HeaderStyle-Width="60" ItemStyle-Width="60" />
        </columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`stylesheet` is as follows

```
TABLE.gvTable
{
    table-layout:fixed;
}
TABLE.gvTable TH
{    
    position:relative;
    border-top-width:0px;
    border-bottom-color:Black;
    background-color:#F5DEB3;
}
```

This is my sample source when i run and click on view source

```
  <div id="pnlWrapper" style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;height:300px;overflow-y:scroll;">
 <div>
 <table class="gvTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" rules="all" border="1" id="gvTheGrid" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
 <tr>
<th scope="col" style="width:60px;">id</th>
</tr><tr>
<td style="width:60px;">10</td>
</tr><tr>
<td style="width:60px;">10</td>
</tr><tr>
<td style="width:60px;">10</td>
</tr><tr>
```

Header shown when page loads

[image]

No header when scrolls down

[image]

Comment: See following links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296020/how-can-i-lock-the-first-row-and-first-column-of-a-table-when-scrolling-possibly http://www.cubido.at/blogs/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=1259

Comment: Unable to view or download the content to use what should i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example [here](http://cross-browser.com/x/examples/xthf-demo.php?s=sep&n=3) that works on IE8.

This was very useful to me since we are moving to IE8 here at work and I needed to get this working.

There are a few tricks with using this solution.  It expects to use the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags which are not rendered by default in the GridView.  In order to render them, you'll need to add something along the lines of the following which was suggested earlier by another.

```
// will add <thead> and <tbody>
gvTheGrid.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
```

I have an example solution working here based upon that link that I sent via email.

Comment: So in place of `<script>` he use is it ok if we place our grid

Comment: It is a solution that is a combination of CSS and JS so it's a bit more complicated but the site is very detailed with documentation and a forum if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to wrap the content of ItemTemplate (You can use Template Column) using   .

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <div style="height:100px; overflow:scroll">
   .....
 </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Take a look at CodeProject article : [Scrollable GridView.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/ScrollableGridview.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how we've done it.

1. create an asp panel with a given height and specify vertical scrollbars
2. put the gridview inside the panel and give it a class of
   myGridView
3. in CSS create the following styles

   TABLE.myGridView
   {
       table-layout:fixed;
   }
   TABLE.myGridView TH
   {  position:relative; }
4. Specify the widths of each asp:BoundField like this:

   HeaderStyle-Width="85" ItemStyle-Width="85"

Here is an example of the code behind:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlWrapper" runat="server" Height="300px" ScrollBars="Vertical" BorderWidth="1px">                
    <asp:GridView ID="gvTheGrid" runat="server" GridLines="Both" CellPadding="3" CssClass="gvTable" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true">                    
        <columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="C" HeaderText="C" HeaderStyle-Width="60" ItemStyle-Width="60" />
        </columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
TABLE.gvTable
{
    table-layout:fixed;
}
TABLE.gvTable TH
{    
    position:relative;
    border-top-width:0px;
    border-bottom-color:Black;
    background-color:#F5DEB3;
}
```

Here is the generated HTML:

```
<div id="ctl00_MainContent_pnlWrapper" style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;height:300px;overflow-y:scroll;">
<div>
<table class="gvTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_MainContent_gvTheGrid" style="background-color:WhiteSmoke;border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr style="font-size:Medium;">
<th scope="col" style="width:60px;">Select One</th>
<th scope="col" style="width:60px;">Number</a></th>
<th scope="col" style="width:60px;">Address</a></th>
<th scope="col" style="width:200px;">Phone</a></th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>               
</div>
```

You can see the classes for the CSS match between the code/generated source.

HTH

Comment: Can you post the design and css that you used i did not get the one as per you said

Comment: Doesn't work for me on any browser i am unable to see the header while scrolling

Comment: Let's see your code.  I am looking at the application now and it works here.  We're on IE7.  I could paste the generated source in a message if that would help.

Comment: @User: I think McArthey's solution doesn't work for you because you are probably not telling the GridView to render the TH tags on the table header. Do this in code behind:  yourGrid.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader; and McArthey's solution should work for you.

Comment: @User are you specifying the appropriate header tags in your BoundField or Template?

Comment: Hi i just wrote as per given by you i did not use th and all

Comment: Try to wrap the <asp:Panel></asp:Panel> tags with table tags so you'd have <table><tr><td><asp:Panel></asp:Panel></table></tr></td>.

Comment: u mean ` <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlWrapper" runat="server" Height="300px" ScrollBars="Vertical" BorderWidth="1px">                
    <asp:GridView ID="gvTheGrid" runat="server" GridLines="Both" CellPadding="3" CssClass="gvTable" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true">                    
        <columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" HeaderStyle-Width="60" ItemStyle-Width="60" />
        </columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>`

Comment: if so it is not working can u mail me the working copy that you have done to me to dora.meka@gmail.com

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3150/discussion-between-mcarthey-and-user)

Comment: Looks like a problem with IE8's implementation of table-layout:fixed.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216591/broken-table-layout-in-ie8-with-embedded-tables-within-another-table
It says to simply add the same CSS property to the outermost table and see if that helps.  I don't have IE8 otherwise I'd check for you.